# How to get data list from the frame and then click the link inside the frame and then click another link in the frame?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I have posted screenshot for you.
I have logged into the website.
I could not able to find how to navigate to this link and click it.
I want to perform following steps

1. Get the list of stocks from the frame and store it
2. select the stock
3. Click the stock
4. Click the chart button / link in the stock
5. Then move to the chart and click the pop-up, it will open the another window.
6. Take the screenshot of the stock and move back to current window.
7. Select the second stock in the last and perform above steps.

My problem:-
i could able to perform login but i could not able to select the stock and the chart icon. when i try to inspect the element, I could not able to select it because, it selects until the stock name. The next step to selecting the chart link / icon is not showing and not possible.
If i can able to perform above steps it will easy for me to write the codes for remaining.

thanks for the guide
please check the screenshots below for your reference.
Thank you so much for the help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Added one more screen shot - i could not able to locate that tag to click and view the chart.
[image]

I tried all the ways. Still i could not able to locate the chart and to click it.

---

My code :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


#browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='userid']").send_keys("*****")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='password']").send_keys("******")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
print(browser.title)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='pin']").send_keys("******")
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
print(browser.title)
#browser.save_screenshot("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/Home.png")
#browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("div.vddl-draggable:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")).click()
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'icon icon-trending-up').click()
#browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a").click()
webdriver.wait(5)


#browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/span[4]/button/span").click()
#browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div").click()
#browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/span[4]/button/span").click()

#browser.find_element() 
#browser.close()
#browser.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market")
time.sleep(5)
#print(browser.title)
#browser.quit()
```

Comment: Also share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Link to code    https://linkode.org/#S1CtB4OsO3OxEjnLBv2YU5

Comment: @vivekrajagopalan Please [edit] your post to include the code as a code block. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. I selected the link by XPATH

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/div[@id='app']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/div[@id='app']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[4]/button[1]/span[1]").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

I need to wait for the browser to load and I found out that Xpath which i have selected is wrong.
I have posted the image
[image]

Thank you so much everyone for the help.

Comment: Check rules for stable XPATHs. Yours may break very soon. Not sure why your question was downvoted.

Comment: Also remember that you only need to set implicit wait once.  It's a global setting.

Comment: Thank you @pcalkins I will set the implicit wait once.